# What is this SATCHMO code for?

Tags: prolog

I have a code of SATCHMO and I have tried to understand it but I could not:

```
Prove(true).

Prove(A & B) :-
    Prove(A),
    Prove(B).

Prove (A or B):-
    Prove(A);
    Prove(B).

Prove(A):-
           P => A,
           Prove(p).

Prove(P):-
           A => B or C
          Prove(A),
          Prove(B => P),
          Prove(C => P). 

Prove (B => P) :-
           assert(B),  
           (prove(P) -> retract (B);  
           (retract(B), fail)).
```

and how can I test it in prolog?

I have somequestions about it and I am looking to hier a tutor who could explain such things.

Comment: Sometimes you write `Prove(...)` which is not standard Prolog syntax, and sometimes you write `prove(...)` which is ok.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a tutor.

Answer (score 2):

Try to learn more about metaprogramming in Prolog:

- [A Couple of Meta-interpreters in Prolog](http://www.logic.at/prolog/acomip/acomip.html)
- [Guide to Prolog Programming - Meta-Interpreters](http://kti.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/meta_interpret.html)

And also look at SATCHMO papers you can find a collection of them in: [Variations on a Theme: A Bibliography on Approaches to Theorem Proving Inspired From Satchmo](http://www.en.pms.ifi.lmu.de/publications/PMS-FB/PMS-FB-2005-45/bry-manthey.pdf)